Why labels do not appear on pie chart in KivyMD application?
I’m currently developing a KivyMD application that includes a pie chart using Matplotlib.
However, the labels are not appearing on the pie chart as expected.
I am using the plt.pie() function to create a pie chart, but the labels for each segment do not show up. The segments are being drawn, but there are no visible labels or percentages.
What could be causing the labels to not display on the pie chart?
Are there any common issues with rendering Matplotlib figures in Kivy that I should be aware of?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Kivy file:
MDFloatLayout:
    id: main_layout
    size: root.width,root.height

    MDBoxLayout:
        id: plot_container

        orientation: "vertical"

        size_hint: None,None

        width: 600

        height: 400

        padding: "5dp"

        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6, "center_y":0.5}

    MDBoxLayout:
        id: menu_bar

        orientation: "vertical"

        size_hint: None,None

        width: 120

        height: root.height

        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.07}

        padding:"5dp"

        spacing: "5dp"

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 163/255,216/255,239/255,1

            Rectangle:
                size:self.size

                pos:self.pos

        canvas.after:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1

            Rectangle:
                source: "img/monitoring-test.png"

                size:60,60

                pos:(25,root.height - 65)

        Widget:
            size_hint: None,None

            width: 115

            height: 60

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 58/255,101/255,153/255,0

                Rectangle:
                    size:self.size

                    pos:self.pos

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "img/bar-chart.png"

            text: "Text1"

            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}

            icon_size: "50sp"

            on_release: app.create_bar_plot()

        MDLabel:
            text: "Text1"

            font_size: "16"

            font_type: "Arial"

            halign: "center"

            bold: True

            color: 0,0,0,1

        Widget:
            size_hint: None,None

            width: 115

            height: 50

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 58/255,101/255,153/255,0.2

                Rectangle:
                    size:self.size

                    pos:self.pos

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "img/pie-chart.png"

            text: "Text1"

            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}

            icon_size: "50sp"

            on_release: app.create_pie_plot()

        MDLabel:
            text: "Text1"

            font_size: "16"

            font_type: "Arial"

            halign: "center"

            bold: True

            color: 0,0,0,1

        Widget:
            size_hint: None,None

            width: 115

            height: 50

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 58/255,101/255,153/255,0.2

                Rectangle:
                    size:self.size

                    pos:self.pos

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "img/bar-chart.png"

            text: "Text1"

            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}

            icon_size: "50sp"

        MDLabel:
            text: "Text1"

            font_size: "16"

            font_type: "Arial"

            halign: "center"

            bold: True

            color: 0,0,0,1

        Widget:
            size_hint: None,None

            width: 115

            height: 50

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 58/255,101/255,153/255,0.2

                Rectangle:
                    size:self.size

                    pos:self.pos

Python file:
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

from kivy.animation import Animation

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from kivy_garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivy

class Dashboard(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.root = Builder.load_file("PoliFyp.kv")
        self.create_bar_plot()
        return self.root

    def create_bar_plot(self):

        plt.clf()

        plot_container = self.root.ids.plot_container

        plot_container.clear_widgets()

        plot_container.width = 600

        plot_container.height = 400


        x = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 100]

        y = [12, 6, 9, 15, 23, 67, 11, 90, 34, 91]

        plt.bar(x, y,8,color='orange')

        plt.ylabel("Y axis")

        plt.xlabel("X axis")

        plot_container.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivy(plt.gcf()))

    def create_pie_plot(self):
        plt.clf()

        plot_container = self.root.ids.plot_container

        plot_container.width = 500

        plot_container.height = 900

        sizes = [12, 6, 9]

        labels = ["APPLE","BANANA","DATES"]  # Example labels

        plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%0.1f%%', startangle=140, textprops={'fontsize': 6})

        plot_container.clear_widgets()

        plot_container.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivy(plt.gcf()))



Dashboard().run()


Adjusted the fontsize and color in textprops. Ensured that the sizes
are not too small to display labels.
Verified that clear_widgets() is
called before adding the new pie chart.
Checked that the background
color of the plot is not obscuring the labels.
The pie chart segments
render correctly, but the labels are missing

